# Applying a window over a list

Tags: signal-processing

The window functions state that they tread over lists, but when I try to do:

HammingWindow/@list, I do not get the expected results. What is the best way to apply a window over an arbitrary length list?

Comment: can you maybe add a working example and the "expected results" that you cannot get? Please also format the code by selecting a piece of text, then clicking on the brackets in the editor.

Comment: len = 1024;
i = Range[1., len];
rect = 1 & /@ i;
wrect = HammingWindow /@ rect;
wrect[[512]] The value of the the Hamming window at this point in the output vector should be 1?

Comment: My real problem is not understanding how to apply a window over an arbitrary length list... When I execute the code I pasted, a get an output vector that is all 0's...

Comment: My goal is to window a vector prior to a Fourier transform, and perform overlap and add filtering of long vectors..

Answer (score 1):

Say the FFT you want to take is going to be of length `nfft`. Then the window also needs to be of length `nfft`. You can get a window of this length by:

```
nfft = 1024;
win = HannWindow[Range[-0.5, 0.5 - 1/nfft, 1/nfft]]
ListPlot[win]
```

[image]

Or change Hann to Hamming if you prefer that window.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Your method and the array call in answer 0 are close...

Answer (score 0):

When a function is Threadable over a list, I would think it would have the built in knowledge to do the following where rect is of arbitrary length (This is most likely user error and does not do what I expect..):

```
wrect = HammingWindow/@rect;
```

The following accomplished the result, by creating a window vector and doing element by element multiplication with an equal size signal vector.

```
length = 1024;
i = Range[1, length];
rect = 1 & /@ i;
window = Array[HammingWindow, length, {-1/2, 1/2}];
wrect = window * rect;
ListLinePlot[wrect]
```

[image: Hamming Window of length]